# Handling of categorical variables: rpart vs tree

Tags: categorical-data, cart, algorithms, categorical-encoding, rpart

For tree and randomForest packages in R, the number of levels for a factor (as a categorical variable) is capped at 32. An explanation might be that the number of comparisons at each split becomes very high (2^32 approximately). Why does rpart still work with a factor with larger no. of levels?

Comment: I don't know the full reason, but CART uses a trick to reduce the number of splits considered.  For regression, the levels of a categorical predictor are replaced by mean of the outcome; for binary responses, levels are replaced by the proportion of outcomes in class 1 (see Elements of Statistical Learning book or [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191055/where-in-elements-of-statistical-learning-does-it-talk-of-a-trick-to-deal-with/191057) for reason).  For categorical predictors, there are some approximations.  I don't know why randomForest caps this at 32.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your help. Are you aware of any detailed documentation for the rpart package (or a research paper, perhaps)?

Comment: Recursive partitioning (CART) requires about n=100,000 to be reliable.  Random forests are for tall and thin datasets and often do not perform well when n is not huge and the number of features is large.

Comment: @Frank Harrell:, where does this n=100,000 figure come from?

Comment: Simulations I've done, and https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-137

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> I don't know the full reason, but CART uses a trick to reduce the
> number of splits considered. For regression, the levels of a
> categorical predictor are replaced by mean of the outcome; for binary
> responses, levels are replaced by the proportion of outcomes in class
> 1 (see Elements of Statistical Learning book or link for reason). For
> categorical predictors, there are some approximations. I don't know
> why randomForest caps this at 32.

– Peter Calhoun

For some alternative ideas see [Random Forest Regression with sparse data in Python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390671/random-forest-regression-with-sparse-data-in-python/430127#430127)